# How to access Facebook page posts with app credentials?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been working on getting an old server-to-server Facebook app working which was previously used to load a feed of page posts for pages we own, but even after completing the review for manage_pages access I still get the error "This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature" when I try to access the feed via 
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/posts?access_token=[app access token] 
or 
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_id]/feed?access_token=[app access token]

I've tried generating the app access token with the Graph API explorer and also tried using [app ID]|[app secret] as the access token, but get the same result either way. Is there something I need to do to grant the app manage_pages access for specific pages now facebook's reviewed it, or is there something else I'm missing? The user that created the app can access the data if using a page access token, but since they removed the ability to create permanent page access tokens that's not really a viable option

edit: Looking into the documentation, it seems I should be able to request a page access token using the app authentication now that it's been approved for manage_pages permissions. However, trying to access one with https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/[page ID]?fields=access_token&access_token=[app access token] also generates the manage_pages or Public Content permissions error, which seems like it would suggest the app doesn't actually have manage pages permissions?

Comment: the error message should be very clear: use manage_pages if you own the page, or apply for page public content access.

Comment: How do I use manage_pages with an app then? That's what I'm not clear on, I've gotten approval for that and as far as I can tell (and from what support said around that review request) it should be able to query this data now it's been approved, but it's not recognizing the app token as having that access level. Do I need to explicitly give it on a per-page basis? If so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: you need to use a page token, not an app token

Comment: How can I get the page token with an app token though? The documentation claims you should be able to, and page tokens expire so I can't just copy one from Graph Explorer, so getting one with the app token seems the only way I can resolve this

Comment: yes, you need to authorize for a user token and get a page token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/